# Excel Combobox VBA issues multiple items

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic range in a combo box that I use as an index with several concat formulas in the workbook. I fill the box on dropbuttonclick with

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

'Updates on drop down
'This place row number in H3 making the dynamic vba combo box work like form control


   Sheets("Home").Shapes("ComboBox1").Select
      With Selection
            .ListFillRange = "ParticipantData!$A$3:$A$" & Sheets("ParticipantData").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
            lngrow = ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
            Range("H3") = lngrow
        End With
    
        
End Sub
```

The issue is when I delete a value from Column A it throws a 438 error on me. The range changes quite often and I'd like to be able to add & delete and names as necessary. I typically copy and past values from a census and need to eliminate the .listfilRange 438 erro. I use the combobox to select a name which pulls data, generates a report and ultimate is saved as a pdf. lngrow is used as the row for the index of a dynamic range PartData in shee "ParticipantData".

Edit: Removed 2nd question

I know I have rofl vba skills, so thank you for your time helping me.

Comment: Seems like 2 different questions here, you should probably post the second question separately.  As to the first question, what is the actual string that you are assigning to `.ListFillRange` when it fails?

Comment: Say I have A3-A12 filled on sheet "participant data". When I clear the contents in a12 i get the 438 error.

Comment: Then what makes you think that the .ListFillRange is the problem?

Comment: that is where the debugger takes me and I figure there is an issue in loading the list then altering it outside of vba. I likely need to clear the list on any cell change in the dynamic range, that is just beyond my skills.

Comment: That in itself is extremely odd.  The only way that the debugger should take you to that line is if you clicked the dropdown or if you have some other code that is calling this code or triggering the event.  Clearing the contents of a cell should never raise an exception through this line of code unless you have a Workbook/worksheet_change event that is calling it.